# Convert from fraction to decimal and vice versa, TI 83 basic

Tags: ti-basic

I have a code to calculate the slope of a line if two points are known; however, it only returns the slope in decimal format. I'd like the ability to choose to convert the decimal to a fraction. Here's what I've done so far:

```
:Disp " "
:Input "PAIR 1: ",T
:Input "PAIR 2: ",U
:((LU(2)-LT(2))/(LU(1)-LT(2)))->M
:Disp "Slope Is:      ",M
:Input "F>>D? Y/N:      ",Str0
:If Str0="Y"
:(M>F<>D)->O
:Disp O
```

When I run this, I get ERROR: SYNTAX on the conversion step (the actual slope calculation completes successfully.)

**Some of the code I've typed above is not exactly how it appears in the TI 84, but it's the best I can do with a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `►Frac` and `►F◄►D` are display tokens, not conversion tokens

TI calculators can only store numbers one way: in their proprietary floating-point format. This means that numbers cannot be "converted" from fraction to decimal or vice versa, only *displayed* as fractions or decimals. Thus, storing to anything (e.g. `3►F◄►D→X`) will throw a syntax error.

Display modes are changed using the `Auto`/`Dec`/`Frac` tokens in the <kbd>MODE</kbd> menu; `►Frac` overrides the mode and displays as a fraction approximation, `►Dec` displays as decimal, and `►F◄►D` tells the calculator to display in the opposite display mode from its current setting.

Quoting from [this page](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/frac):

> ►Frac attempts to display the input in fraction form. It only works on the home screen outside a program, or with the Disp and Pause commands in a program.

Comment: Perfect. I see how the link says "It only works on the home screen outside a program, or with the Disp and Pause commands in a program." Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you get the >F<>D->X formatting? You can see in my original post that I was unable to do this.

Comment: You can use TI's Data Editor to transfer the program to the computer, and then pull the characters from there, or you can manually find the Unicode BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER and BLACK LEFT-POINTING POINTER as I did.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is in the line

```
(M>F<>D)->O
Disp O
```

There's no reason to format it this way when it can simply be expressed as

```
Disp M>F<>D
```

which calculates properly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert from decimal to a fraction is to use the Euclidean Algorithm. Here it is in ti-basic

```
:Ans→X:{1,abs(Ans
:Repeat E‾9>Ans(2
:abs(Ans(2){1,fPart(Ans(1)/Ans(2
:End
:round({X,1}/Ans(1),0
:Ans/gcd(Ans(1),Ans(2
```

`Ans` is the decimal you wish to convert
and `E‾9` is the same as 10^(-9)